# Iterate over character in string with index

Tags: python

Let me explain my problem with a real life code example:

```
message = "hello"
for char in message:
    print(char)
```

This program output is:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

But i want to know character position. when i use `str.index()` it become:

```
message = "hello"
for char in message:
    print(char, message.index(char))
```

Output:

```
h 0
e 1
l 2
l 2
o 4
```

The `L` position is 2, and not 2 and 3!
How can i get character position while iterating over this message?

Comment: `inex` isn't a valid method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.index()` finds the *first* index of an element in the given list. If it appears multiple times, only the first occurrence is returned.

If you want to get pairs of elements and their respective indexes, you can use the built-in function `enumerate()`:

```
for idx, char in enumerate(message):
    print(char, idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
message = "hello"
for count, char in enumerate(message):
    print(char, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
message = "hello"
for i, char in enumerate(message):
    print(char, i)
```

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted your code with enumerate, this should work

```
    message = "hello"
    for index,char in enumerate(message):
        print(char,index)
```

You can find some documentation about it in the official python docs or [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Comment: `index` should come second.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,char in enumerate(message):
    print(char,i)
```